# Question about various power/ground sources in one circuit

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, breadboard

I would like some advice on how to handle different power/ground lines on the same circuit. I am not clear about how to wire-up multiple peripherals etc. with their own power sources in a single circuit. For example, i am breadboarding a MCU (with a external 5v supply) and have a USB-UART (or a RS232-UART) connecting it to a PC. So now i have two power sources, one from the USB/RS232 and the other from the circuit power supply. How should the wiring be done so as not to fry anything? I see two options.

- Connect power and ground to the entire circuit from the USB/RS232 source (i.e. USB powered) and turn off the external power supply. Use the power/ground lines exposed from the UART device for this.
- Power everything from the external power supply. In this case the power pin from the USB is NOT connected to anywhere in the circuit. However the circuit ground is connected to the USB ground (exposed via a UART pin). This seems wrong to me since they could be at different potentials and hence might lead to problems.

So what is the correct way to wire up USB-UART, USB-JTAG etc. from a host to a circuit?

Comment: This is actually quite a good question, especially if you have modern CMOS logic on your board that'll power up quite happily from a logic HIGH input via the upper ESD diode on that input pin...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am a beginner in Electronics and hence have these basic questions :-). However i can find no clear answers to the above question. Most advice to tie ground lines together even though they are from different sources. Why? If i "know" that all of them work in the 0-5v range then i shouldn't have to tie the ground lines either. Each will source/sink voltages in the 0-5v range and everything should be fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The grounds do need to be tied together -- but the *power* nets are what's interesting here....

Comment: Power supplies are not all alike (some float & some are grounded) and not all power outlets in, say, a house or on a stage are at the same ground potential.  If your digital logic needs to talk to one another they all need to "see" the same ground.  So the grounds need to be connected.  If you are blowing out power supplies or your digital logic, consider using power supplies where the ground is floating.  Or plug all your power supplies into the same power strip.

Comment: And yes, the power up sequence of logic circuits can make a difference.  But the interface you are using (usb) is usually designed to prevent problems.